# Webpack - devtool: source-map for CSS and eval-source-map for JS?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, source-maps

If I use devtool: 'source-map' it works great with CSS:

[image: I'm getting the file, row and everything is awesome]

But, my JavaScript variable names are no fun:

[image: Mangeled JavaScript vars]

So, if I use devtool: eval-source-maps. Life is great - debugging JS. But my CSS then points to the big bundle-css instead of the separate files:

[image: Great times debugging JS!]

[image: This is no fun...]

How do I have my cake and eat it too?!
I would like to use eval-source-map for JS and source-map for CSS during the same build.

This is my webpack config (using the latest of everything as of this writing):

```
/* eslint no-console:"off" */
const {resolve} = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ProgressBarPlugin = require('progress-bar-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const InlineManifestWebpackPlugin = require('inline-manifest-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const {getIfUtils, removeEmpty} = require('webpack-config-utils');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
// const OfflinePlugin = require('offline-plugin/runtime').install();

module.exports = (env) => {
    const {ifProd, ifNotProd} = getIfUtils(env);
    const config = {
        context: resolve('src'),
        entry: './js/index/index.js',
        output: {
            filename: 'bundle.[name].[hash].js',
            path: resolve('dist'),
            pathinfo: ifNotProd()
        },
        // devtool: 'source-map' //This works for CSS but not JS,
        devtool: 'eval-source-map' //This works for JS but not css
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    exclude: /(node_modules)/
                },
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    loader: 'eslint-loader',
                    exclude: /(node_modules)/
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        fallback: 'style-loader',
                        use: [
                            {
                                loader: 'css-loader',
                                options: {importLoaders: 1, minimize: false, sourceMap: true}
                            }
                        ]
                    })
                },
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'html-loader'
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                    loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff',
                    query: {
                        name: 'static/media/files/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
                    }
                }, {
                    test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    query: {
                        name: 'static/media/fonts/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/,
                    loader: 'url-loader?limit=25000',
                    query: {
                        limit: 10000,
                        name: 'static/media/images/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: removeEmpty([
            // ifProd(new InlineManifestWebpackPlugin()),
            // ifProd(new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            //     names: ['manifest']
            // })),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: './index.html'
                // inject: 'head'
            }),
            // new OfflinePlugin(),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env': {
                    NODE_ENV: ifProd('"production"', '"development"')
                }
            }),
            new UglifyJSPlugin({
                    parallel: {
                        cache: true
                    },
                    sourceMap: true
                }
            ),
            new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
                cssProcessorOptions: {
                    preset: 'default',
                    map: {inline: false}
                }
            }),
            new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.[name].[hash].css'),
            new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
            new ProgressBarPlugin(),
        ])
    };
    if (env.debug) {
        console.log(config);
        debugger // eslint-disable-line
    }
    return config;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work:

```
{
  ...webpackConfig,
  devtool: false,
  plugins: [
    new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
      test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/
    }),
    new webpack.EvalSourceMapDevToolPlugin({
      test: /\.(vue|[jt]sx?)$/
    }),
  ]
}
```

This will give you inline-source-map for css, scss and sass and eval-source-map for vue, js, jsx, ts and tsx

Comment: This sadly does not seem to work for CSS files that are imported within a .js file. Any ideas on how to adjust for that? Still gets handled with eval-sourcemap instead of sourcemap.

Comment: Update, turns out nothing to do with imports from a JS file. Got it working by adding `columns: true` to the first plugin (CSS). In addition I also had to modify the regex as CSS filenames seem to have the version has in there too. Result: `new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({ test: /\.s?[ac]ss(\?hash=[A-z0-9]*)?$/, columns: true })`

Comment: But @redfox05 it looks like `columns` defaults to `true` according to https://webpack.js.org/plugins/eval-source-map-dev-tool-plugin and https://webpack.js.org/plugins/source-map-dev-tool-plugin unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @god_is_love Can't really remember now, but it was the only thing I changed, so....